# Excluding emacs temporary files from Jekyll

Tags: emacs, jekyll

Jekyll seems happy to exclude emacs `filename~` and `filename.~n~` backup files, but I can't make it exclude `#filename#` or `.#filename#`.  While they don't actually copy over to the published site, they constantly trigger file regeneration as I edit files in watched mode.

Is there anything I can put in `exclude` or some other setting stop this behaviour?

Comment: Have you tried adding `"*#"` to the `exclude` pattern list?

Comment: I have both `"#*"` and `".#*"` in the `exclude` pattern list, but I'll give `"*#"` a shot...

Comment: Adding `"*#*"` to the exclude pattern list did not make any difference.

Comment: What version of Jekyll do you have?  The one I just installed from the Mint repo is ancient and doesn't have exclude wildcard handling at all.

Comment: I'm using Jekyll 3.7.4 (the latest, last I checked a week ago?).

Comment: I believe this is still an outstanding issue as of Jekyll 3.7.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to figure out if the `#` was a special character WRT pattern matching in Ruby, but I'm learning Ruby fresh as I learn Jekyll so ...?  As a random, maybe it'll work attempts, `\#` and `##` are unhelpful.

So, from the Emacs side, I modified `auto-save-file-name-p` and `make-auto-save-file-name` to add a `~` on the end of auto-save files, so they are now `#filename#~` and Jekyll happily ignores files that end with `~` (see: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Auto_002dSaving.html).

Lastly I also turned off lockfiles which creates the `.#filename` files.

This works, even if it would probably be better to have fixed it from the Jekyll source side.

So, if this is an issue for you, put the following in your `.emacs`:

```
(defun auto-save-file-name-p (filename)
            "Return non-nil if FILENAME can be yielded by..."
            (string-match "^#.*#~$" filename))

(defun make-auto-save-file-name ()
            "Return file name to use for auto-saves \
          of current buffer.."
            (if buffer-file-name
                (concat
                 (file-name-directory buffer-file-name)
                 "#"
                 (file-name-nondirectory buffer-file-name)
                 "#~")
              (expand-file-name
               (concat "#%" (buffer-name) "#~"))))

(setq create-lockfiles nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a "partial" solution, I had a similar problem as I as my backup filenames were set to *.*~1 *.*~2 etc. (partial because it doesn't work for files like "_redirects" that are within an "include:" set : I still end up w/ a "_redirects~" file in _site

tried everything within the _config.yml file :

```yaml
# exclude:
# - *~*
# - *.*~1
# - "_*~1"
```

none works, it seems that starting w/ an unprotected wildcard * is forbidden,
until I noticed the excluded file in the "--verbose" transcript have a starting /
even for the file in sub-directories so this is it the solution : use a / at be beginning of the pattern.

what WORKs :

```yaml
exclude:
 - /*#
 - /*~*
```